# Find if a cell value is a part of some other cell in a list

Tags: excel

I know I can search in Excel if some cell exact value appears in some selection, for example

```
A         B
cat       dog
          black dog
          black cat              
          cat

C1=MATCH(A1;B1:B4;0)
```

which will give me 4 - the first row in B1:B4 where "cat" appears.

But I would like to search for first cell that CONTAINS my text but ISN'T EQUAL to it, so in my case it would be 3 as "black cat" contains "cat" and "black cat"<>"cat"

Is it possible without VBA?

Answer (score 4):

You're effectively matching with 2 conditions  - A1 is contained within the text **and** A1 <> the text, so you can use this version with `MATCH`

`=MATCH(1;INDEX((B1:B4<>A1)*(SEARCH(A1;B1:B4)>0);0);0)`

I used semi-colons as separators rather than commas because it appears that you need those for your region

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards in `MATCH`. So I think you could achieve this with a function like

```
 =IF(OR(ISNA(MATCH(A2&"?*",B1:B5,0)),ISNA(MATCH("*?"&A2,B1:B5,0))),IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2&"?*",B1:B5,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH("*?"&A2,B1:B5,0)),-1,MATCH("*?"&A2,B1:B5,0)),MATCH(A2&"?*",B1:B5,0)),IF(MATCH("*?"&A2,B1:B5,0)<MATCH(A2&"?*",B1:B5,0),MATCH("*?"&A2,B1:B5,0),MATCH(A2&"?*",B1:B5,0)))
```

This function makes sure there is at least 1 character before or after Cat, so it won't match Cat directly.

Here is some documentation for [MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php)

---

NB. As mentioned in the comments, you may have to change `,` for `;` as your locale appears to be different to mine.

Comment: This won't necessarily find the first match - If you change B2 in the above sample from **"dog"** to **"cat flap"** then that should be the first valid match - but formula still returns 3 - see my answer

Comment: ...and if "cat flap" is the only value in B1:B5 containing "cat" then formula returns #N/A...

Comment: I think you'd still need to add another IF because if B1 = **"black cat"** and B2 = **"cat flap"** you get 2 rather than 1

Comment: Yes.. You're right (again). I made an edit, but it's one nasty formula now..  Your answer is far more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, it works good enough for my data and I learnt about wildcards. Just I wouldn't advice anybody to use it with millions of rows, it's quite slow, took about 30 seconds for 50000 rows.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, glad it worked. @barryhoudini solution is far better though I think.